# How can I fix the ImportError ("No module named pygame") on executing a python file?

Tags: python, pygame

After typing `SnakeGame.py` I am getting the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "SnakeGame.py", line 1, in 
> import pygame
> ImportError: No module named pygame).

Pls give me a solution on how to solve this, I have installed pygame also.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That error means that the python interpreter isn't able to find the pygame module.
Are you using a virtual environment? If you are using an IDE like PyCharm, try to install the pygame module inside the IDE console.

pip install pygame

Answer (score 0):

install  pygame in  CMD  write pip install pygame
if you use visual studio code  go to market and type pygame then install it ...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72jZ9.png)

visual studio code

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem a few days ago. My solution was to use a virtual environment. To do this, open a terminal in your folder and use the following commands: 1.) pip install pipenv 2.) pipenv shell 3.) pipenv install pygame

After this, you need to select the correct python interpreter. In VS Code, hit ctrl+shift+p Then click the correct interpreter (should have the name of the folder). Then try to run the file. If that doesn't work, try to run this in the terminal: pipenv run {name of the python file, example: app.py}

Hope that works for you